# Spring Rest Hibernate create nested object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have 3 models PaymentPlan, PaymentPlanDetail, PaymentPlanElement

PaymentPlan has one or many PaymentPlanDetail,
PaymentPlanElement has one or many PaymentPlanDetail,

There is a relationship as the following:

```
public class PaymentPlan{

  //

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "paymentPlan",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<PaymentPlanDetail> paymentPlanDetails= new ArrayList<>();  
}

public class PaymentPlanDetail{

  //

  @ManyToOne(name = paymentPlanElementId)
  private PaymentPlanElement paymentPlanElement;  
}

public class PaymentPlanElement{

  //

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "paymentPlanElement",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<PaymentPlanDetail> paymentPlanDetails= new ArrayList<>  
}
```

I send request object that looks like

```
 {
    name:'foo',

    paymentPlanDetails: [
      {
        name: 'bar',
        paymentPlanElement:{
          id: 12,
          style: 'baz'
        }
      }
    ]

  }
```

The payment plan element is already created,
I want to send JSON object and save payment plan including payment plan details but I got error that `payment_plan_id is null`,
Is there any way to do this in one transaction?

edit:
My PaymentPlan Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/payment-plans")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PaymentPlanController {

  private final PaymentPlanService paymentPlanService;

  @PostMapping
  public PaymentPlan create(@RequestBody PaymentPlan paymentPlan) {
    return paymentPlanService.create(paymentPlan);
  }

}
```

and PaymentPland DTO

`public interface PaymentPlanDao extends JpaRepository<PaymentPlan, Integer> {
}`

Comment: Can we see the code where you look up the `PaymentPlan` based on the request?

Comment: @RobertBain what do you mean

Comment: You've provided your JPA entity class and the json you're sending in the request but how are you persisting the entity? What does your controller look like?

Comment: That all looks good, we need to see the service code now, and dao code (implementation not the interface) if you're calling that from the service. That's where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="paymentPlan")  
 private PaymentPlan paymentPlan;

 Add this to Your PaymentPlanDetail Class As it will Map both the classes As Above map other class too.
```

Hope it helps.